# Query for LAST WEEK starting from monday

Tags: sql, date, hana, weekday, sapb1

I need your help please .

I'm using SAP HANA for B1

I have a table for Invoice = OINV TO

```
 SELECT T0."DocNum" , T0."DocDate" FROM OINV T0
```

I want a query that get the invoice from last week starting from Monday .
For example , we are in Friday 16/09/2022 , i want the query to show me INVOICE from last weeks starting from Monday 05/09/2022 to 11/09/2022

Regards

Comment: Apparently there is a `weekday()` function and an `adddays()` that you can combine to get there: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/fc5ace7a367c434190a8047881f92ed8/d5546c7e7da24b2db555c8ef2cdc91f0.html?version=2.0.04

Comment: yes i saw it , it's indeed the good function but i dont now how to use it correctly for my case , can you please help with my exemple . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys , i found the solution

```
SELECT ADD_DAYS (CURRENT_DATE,( WEEKDAY( now() ) * -1 ) - 7 ) "StartDate",
     ADD_DAYS (CURRENT_DATE,( WEEKDAY( now() ) * -1 ) - 1 ) "EndDate" ,
T0."DocDate"
        FROM OINV T0 
        INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" 
        WHERE T0."DocDate" >= ADD_DAYS (CURRENT_DATE,
     ( WEEKDAY( now() ) * -1 ) - 7 ) 
        AND T0."DocDate" <= ADD_DAYS (CURRENT_DATE,
     ( WEEKDAY( now() ) * -1 ) - 1 ))) WITH READ ONLY
```

Comment: Yep, that's working. But wouldn't it be less cumbersome to have the condition `WHERE ISOWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) = ISOWEEK(ADD_DAYS(T0."DocDate",7))`, which is returning the same result set?

Comment: mark this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

SQL will be like this

SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE {columnThatRecordsDate} > '2022-09-05' and {columnThatRecordsDate} < '2022-09-11'

edit for OP comment

```
SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE YEARWEEK(columnThatRecordsDate) = YEARWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Comment: This was an exemple . I want it to always start the first day of the week (monday) and the last day (sunday) of the last week . For exemple if i run the script in one week , (friday next week for exemple) it will show me result from 12/09/2022 to 18/09/2022

Comment: Ah I see. For that SQL you can use this...
WHERE YEARWEEK(columnThatRecordsDate) = YEARWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
this will always go back 1 calendar week instead of just 7 days previous or specific date.

Comment: Thanks , do you know how to transcript it in SAP HANA Query ?

Comment: I think you can run sql in SAP HANA. https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/c0c984fbbb5710149c7be707c74ad231.html?version=2.0.02

Comment: Yes, you can run sql against HANA (it's a database). However, the above query doesn't match the dialect. An overview of date functions on HANA can be found here: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/e8e6c8142e60469bb401de5fdb6f7c00/34c3ce458ae34d549140b4217b252369.html?locale=en-US

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this. IMHO the easiest is to use functions [WEEK](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20f5758b7519101498b28e41757fe664.html) or [ISOWEEK](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20e23edc7519101482eae3271722de36.html). When going forward with `WEEK`, you also need to consider checking for the correct year, which is why I would prefer this version:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (DOCNUM INTEGER, DOCDATE DATE);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, '15.9.2022');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2, '8.9.2022');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3, '1.9.2022');

SELECT * 
FROM TEST
WHERE ISOWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) = ISOWEEK(ADD_DAYS(DOCDATE,7))
```

Note, that the year is part of the output of `ISOWEEK`.